# Android. Слушатель Spinner'а Lang срабатывает даже при СОЗДАНИИ активности. Как сделать,чтобы он срабатывал только при выборе элемента Спиннера?

Tags: android, android-spinner, listener

```
package mate.files;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Counter for Spinner's Listener
    int Counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        //Title Font
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WelcomeTitle);
        Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Title.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
        //Button Font
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        button.setTypeface(typeFace);

        //Lang Spinner
        Spinner Lang = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Lang);
        ArrayAdapter<?> Adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Langs, R.layout.my_spinner);
        Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_dropdn);
        Lang.setAdapter(Adapter);

        Locale CurLang = this.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
        Resources res = this.getResources();
        android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        if (CurLang.toString().equals("en_US")) {
            Lang.setSelection(0);
        }
        if (CurLang.toString().equals("ru_RU")) {
            Lang.setSelection(1);
        }


//СЛУШАТЕТЕЛЬ ТУТ   |
//                  V

        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    switch (position) {
                        default:
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            conf.setLocale(new Locale("en_US"));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            conf.setLocale(new Locale("ru_RU"));
                            break;
                    }
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, null);
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        };
        Lang.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener);
    }


    public void GetStartedClicked(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeAccount.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Подключать его позже не вариант?

Comment: А куда? Тут позже некуда...

Comment: Тут вы заблуждаетесь: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: Варианта тут два: либо подписываться на событие после первой отрисовки контрола; либо всякие трюки типа этого https://stackoverflow.com/a/30253459/5479247

Comment: Я всё-таки не понял: как подписаться на событие позже? Куда?

Comment: Последняя строчка в `onCreate()` не обязательно должна быть именно там. Подписываться на события (и отписываться) можно в любой момент жизненного цикла.

Comment: Из любого другого места слушатель недоступен: ```Lang.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener)``` - ошибка